# put one div to the right of another div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs like this

```
    <div class="csss_markdown_input">
        <form method="post" class="form csss_markdown_preview_input">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <a href="https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics" target="_blank">Basic Markdown</a><br>
            <a href="https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html" target="_blank">More Markdown Examples</a><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
        
            {%  if message is None %}
                <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" required>Play with Markdown Examples here</textarea>
            {%  else %}
                <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" required>{{ message|safe }}</textarea>          
            {%  endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="csss_markdown csss_markdown_preview_output" >{{md|safe}}</div>
```

and my CSS is like this

```
.csss_markdown_preview_input {
    float: left
}

.csss_markdown_preview_output {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to style my DIvs such that `csss_markdown_preview_output` is always to the right of `csss_markdown_preview_input`. Right now, if `csss_markdown_preview_output` has a paragraph is that is very long, it goes below `csss_markdown_preview_input` in order to take full advantage of the width on the newline. But I want it to instead take up as much width as it can **but** still restrain itself to the width that is the right of `csss_markdown_preview_input` DIV.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them with a block element, give the block element a width of 100%. Make them inline-block elements. Give them a width of 49%. Remove all padding and all margins.

Request detailed examples if needed and I will be glad to provide them.

Comment: would have a 2% lost space. i you use this css : * {box-sizing: border-box; }. you will be able to use padding and borders if you wish, and specify 50% witdh.

Answer (score 0):

just make a table with two columns, fixed layout, so that it respects the width répartition even when you have oversized data, and never go one under the other.

```
<table style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 50%">Input</th>
        <th style="width: 50%">Output</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose both in a `div`

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="csss_markdown_input">
        <form method="post" class="form csss_markdown_preview_input">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <a href="https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics" target="_blank">Basic Markdown</a><br>
            <a href="https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html" target="_blank">More Markdown Examples</a><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
    
            {%  if message is None %}
                <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" required>Play with Markdown Examples here</textarea>
            {%  else %}
                <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" required>{{ message|safe }}</textarea>          
            {%  endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="csss_markdown csss_markdown_preview_output" >{{md|safe}}</div>
</div >



.csss_markdown_preview_input {
    width:'50%';
}

.csss_markdown_preview_output {
    float: left;
    width:'50%';
    margin-left: '50%';
}
```

Comment: you can adjust the widths there

Answer (score 0):

In your css file add this css value and property :  `body{box-sizing:border-box}`

then in your main file you need to use like these:

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="csss_markdown_input" >
        <form method="post" class="form csss_markdown_preview_input">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <a href="https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics" target="_blank">Basic Markdown</a><br>
            <a href="https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html" target="_blank">More Markdown Examples</a><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
        
            {%  if message is None %}
                <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" required>Play with Markdown Examples here</textarea>
            {%  else %}
                <textarea name="message" cols="60" rows="5" required>{{ message|safe }}</textarea>          
            {%  endif %}
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="csss_markdown csss_markdown_preview_output" >{{md|safe}}</div>

   </div>
```

In your css file add this:

```
body{
box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container{
   width:100%
   display:inline-block;
}

.css_markdown_input{
  width:50%;
  
}

.csss_markdown{
  width:50%;
  float-left;
}
```

If it doesn't work for you you can try more:

```
body{
box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container{
   width:100%
   position:relative;
   height: */that you need and use vh*/
}

.css_markdown_input{
 position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
  
}

.csss_markdown{
  position:absolute;
top:50%;
right:50%;
}
```

Comment: problem with this solution is that the widths for the divs are fixed at 50%. What I am looking for is more that the left DIV grows and shrinks when the user modifies the textarea that it contains and the right DIV grows and shrinks accordingly.